# In How Much Time Will My App Publish On Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have completed all the requirements and Published the App. But it seems to be in the reviewed state as you can see in the Picture attached.
In how much time will my App approved or rejected by the Google Play Team?

The Picture is attached here.
Update status
schedule
In review
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Team Normally takes up to 14 days or less to review your app.
In the screenshot attached it is saying that you have completed all the steps now you just have to wait for google to review your app for their policy.
If your app follows the google play policy you will receive the Approved Message otherwise they will let you know about the problem in your app.
Just stay Patient.

Comment: okayy great then that's what i needed. No problem i will wait :D thank you alot for answering.. that's my first question on stackoverflow